Msgpackr partial unpack
I've run into an issue where I'd like to stop decoding/parsing a msgpacker message
(in NodeJS) after I hit a key or after some condition is hit. For example, say I have
const o = {
"astring" : "Blah blah blah",
"anumber" : 1234,
"anotherstring" : "Foo foo foo"
...
}
I serialize the entire object, but later, I might only want to grab "astring" (perhaps
it is a name) and ignore the remainder of the data. Is there some clever way to use the
msgpackr library to do this (without re-writing the decoder/unpacker)?
I have looked at msgpackr-extract, but it isn't always a string field I will want.
I have tried to use the stream api, but the stream is defined over complete objects.
